# Count of unique characters in string

Tags: scala

I need to write a function that returns a `List` of `(Char, Int)` pairs given an input `String`.

My solution produces the correct result but I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
def countChars(s: String): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    s.groupBy(c => c.toLower).flatMap(e => List((e._1, e._2.length))).toList
  }
```

This produces a result like this in a worksheet:

```
countChars("Green Grass")
// res0: List[(Char, Int)] = List(('e', 2), ('s', 2), ('n', 1), ('a', 1), (' ', 1), ('g', 2), ('r', 2))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making a singleton List just to flatten it is redundant.

```
"Green Grass".groupBy(c => c.toLower).map(e => (e._1, e._2.length)).toList
```

Comment: Good point. For some reason I though I had to use flatMap, so in order for it to even work I had to make List for each result. The answer by @nietaki looks interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

If you were working on long Strings or Streams of Chars, your approach would be unnecessarily using too much memory - before you call `flatMap` you are basically storing all the letters from the input string. Instead you can just store the occurrence counts for each of the letters:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
"Green Grass".map(_.toLower).foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int]) { (m, char) =>
  val count = m.getOrElse(char, 0)
  m.updated(char, count+1)
}.toList
```

this returns the same result as your solution.

Comment: fyi: you don't need to import `immutable.Map`.  it's always automatically loaded by `Predef`

Comment: I know, I just wanted to signify which `Map` I'm using :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, we can use the [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is a one-pass alternative to `groupBy`/`mapValues`:

```
"Green Grass".groupMapReduce(_.toLower)(_ => 1)(_ + _).toList
// List[(Char, Int)](('e', 2), ('s', 2), ('n', 1), ('a', 1), (' ', 1), ('g', 2), ('r', 2))
```

This:

- `group`s characters by their lower case version (`_.toLower`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (`_ => 1`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).
- transforms the resulting `Map[Char,Int]` into a `List[(Char, Int)]` with `.toList`.

The `groupMapeduce` stage is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
"Green Grass".groupBy(_.toLower).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_+_))
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit glorified version of @dhg asnwer:

```
"Green Grass".groupBy(c => c.toLower).mapValues(group => group.length).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

```
def countChars(s: String) =
  s.distinct.map(c => c -> s.count(_ == c))
```

Comment: This turns what should be a linear operation into a quadratic one, traversing `s` for every `c`.